# What's the difference between TypeScript const assertions and declarations?

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

I just read about the new `const` assertion feature in TypeScript 3.4 RC and I'm not seeing how it does anything differently from using `const` declarations.

I tested this out using an example from the [announcement page](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-4-rc) that apparently demonstrates how using `as const` (`const` assertion) prevents literal types from being widened (e.g., `"circle"` to `string`).

```
// Example from official announcement
function getShapes() {
  let result = [
    { kind: "circle", radius: 100 },
    { kind: "square", sideLength: 50 },
  ] as const;

  return result;
}

for (const shape of getShapes()) {
  if (shape.kind === "circle") {
    console.log("Circle radius", shape.radius);
  } else {
    console.log("Square side length", shape.sideLength);
  }
}

// Output:
// Circle radius 100
// Square side length 50
```

However, when I removed the `const` assertion and used a `const` declaration instead, nothing changed in the compiler output *or* console output and no errors were thrown.

```
// Altered getShapes function
function getShapes() {
  const result = [
    { kind: "circle", radius: 100 },
    { kind: "square", sideLength: 50 },
  ];

  return result;
}
```

**So what's the difference?** The announcement page lists three reasons to use `const` assertions:

> • no literal types in that expression should be widened (e.g. no going from "hello" to string)
>   • object literals get readonly properties
>   • array literals become readonly tuples

but it doesn't explain how assertions and declarations are different.

Comment: Your example isn't making use of the `Shape` type as the announcement example is. You'll see the difference if you include that in your own example.

Comment: @Aaron I'm not sure what you mean. My altered example is the exact same as the initial one but with the changed `const` use.

Comment: add the return type annotation to `getShapes()` and you'll see the "terrible error message" (announcement wording) that TS gives you *without* const assertion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This example uses `console.log` to test inferred types. `console.log` does not care much about its argument type, so there are no errors in both cases.

The result is different if the test requires more specific type:

```
// Altered getShapes function
function getShapes() {
  const result = [
    { kind: "circle", radius: 100 },
    { kind: "square", sideLength: 50 },
  ];

  return result;
}

for (const shape of getShapes()) {
  if (shape.kind === "circle") {
    const radius: number = shape.radius;
  } else {
    const length: number = shape.sideLength;
  }
}
```

With `--strictNullChecks` on, you will get two errors:

```
t.ts:25:11 - error TS2322: Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.

25     const radius: number = shape.radius;
             ~~~~~~

t.ts:29:11 - error TS2322: Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.

29     const length: number = shape.sideLength;
             ~~~~~~
```

As advertised for this feature, there are no errors when `as const` assertion is used to make the compiler to infer precise type.

For reference, here's the type inferred for return type of `getShapes()` with `const` declaration:

```
 ( { kind: string; radius: number; sideLength?: undefined; } 
  |{ kind: string; sideLength: number; radius?: undefined; } ) []
```

As you can see, `kind` is widened to `string`, and array element type is a union with elements that have all properties declared, only some of them are optional in some union members - that's why you get no errors in console log when you are logging for example `shape.radius` - `console.log` will happily log `undefined` if the union member is of the wrong type.

Here's the type inferred for return type of `getShapes()` with `as const` assertion:

```
readonly [
   { readonly kind: "circle"; readonly radius: 100; }, 
   { readonly kind: "square"; readonly sideLength: 50; }
]
```

Now it's readonly tuple type, not an array, and it has precise types for each tuple member (and `kind` is proper literal type, as expected).

Comment: So why ever use `const` declarations when creating objects or array types in the future if `const` assertion does more?

Comment: Not everyone needs more, `as const` assertion makes everything deeply read-only, so there will be type errors if you try to change for example `radius` of the first element in-place in the array returned by `getShapes()`, unlike with `const` declaration. So if your are not into "everything should be immutable" paradigm then `as const` assertion might be too much in some cases.

Answer (score 4):

A `const` declaration is a variable declaration that can't be changed after declaration. This is a Javascript feature that Typescript supports.

```
const x ={ n: 10} ;
x.n = 11; //ok
x= { n:11}; // error
```

`const` assertion is a type assertion that has the impact you described on the assertion target.

```
const x ={ n: 10} as const;
x. n = 11; // error n is readonly
```

Comment: Makes sense. So the example from the announcement is just a bad example then.

Comment: @Adam Your example lacks the use of the `Shape` type that the announcement example uses to show the behavior.

Comment: Nevertheless, this is exactly one of the examples used in the release announcement. They should have used a different one.