# What does the "as const" mean in TypeScript and what is its use case?

Tags: typescript, type-assertion

I am confused about the `as const` cast. I checked a few documents and videos but did not understand it fully.

My concern is what does the `as const` mean in the code below and what is the benefit of using it?

```js
const args = [8, 5] as const;
const angle = Math.atan2(...args);
console.log(angle);
```

Comment: They're **const**ants. They cannot be changed after they've been declared. It's the same was as `1` will always be `one (1)` in maths, numbers are constants because they cannot be changed.

Comment: See: https://dev.to/adamcoster/the-typescript-as-const-trick-2f4o

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between TypeScript const assertions and declarations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55230653/whats-the-difference-between-typescript-const-assertions-and-declarations)

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions)?

Comment: @jcalz I think we can leave this open and let this question become that canonical for “what is as const”.  Your answer here is really great 

Comment: Up to date documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-inference

Answer (score 560, accepted):

This is known as a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions).  A `const` assertion tells the compiler to infer the *narrowest*<sup>*</sup> or *most specific* type it can for an expression.  If you leave it off, the compiler will use its default type inference behavior, which will possibly result in a *wider* or *more general* type.

Note that it is called an "assertion" and not a "cast".  The term "cast" is generally to be avoided in TypeScript; when people say "cast" they often imply some sort of effect that can be observed at runtime, but TypeScript's type system, including type assertions and `const` assertions, is completely [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) from the emitted JavaScript.  So there is absolutely no difference *at runtime* between a program that uses `as const` and one that does not.

---

At compile time, though, there is a noticeable difference.   Let's see what happens when you leave out `as const` in the above example:

```
const args = [8, 5];
// const args: number[]
const angle = Math.atan2(...args); // error! Expected 2 arguments, but got 0 or more.
console.log(angle);
```

The compiler sees `const args = [8, 5];` and infers the type of `number[]`.  That's a mutable array of zero or more elements of type `number`.  The compiler has no idea *how many* or *which* elements there are.  Such an inference is generally reasonable; often, array contents are meant to be modified in some way.  If someone wants to write `args.push(17)` or `args[0]++`, they'll be happy with a type of `number[]`.

Unfortunately the next line, `Math.atan2(...args)`, results in an error.  The `Math.atan2()` function requires exactly two numeric arguments.  But all the compiler knows about `args` is that it's an array of numbers.  It has completely forgotten that there are two elements, and so the compiler complains that you are calling `Math.atan2()` with "0 or more" arguments when it wants exactly two.

---

Compare that to the code with `as const`:

```
const args = [8, 5] as const;
// const args: readonly [8, 5]
const angle = Math.atan2(...args); // okay
console.log(angle);
```

Now the compiler infers that `args` is of type `readonly [8, 5]`... a [`readonly` tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-tuple-types) whose values are exactly the numbers `8` and `5` in that order.  Specifically, `args.length` is known to be exactly `2` by the compiler.

And this is enough for the next line with `Math.atan2()` to work.  The compiler knows that `Math.atan2(...args)` is the same as `Math.atan2(8, 5)`, which is a valid call.

---

And again: at runtime, there is no difference whatsoever. Both versions log `1.0121970114513341` to the console.  But `const` assertions, like the rest of the static type system, are not meant to have effects at runtime.  Instead, they let the compiler know more about the *intent* of the code, and can more accurately tell the difference between correct code and bugs.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=24&pln=9&pc=1#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEA5A9gJzCANkg3gFBIlLxrBQAuSIGA5lEgLxIDaAHADRICsAugG5ipAPSiyFarQZQAXEmABXMACMIGNvxElylGiGD0cyVgFkQVABYA6S4YBMAChuu6jAJSCk4pBoyYAIRIAKIAHjAQ8FQQACZIDjL0KhDAVFA8qko09Gg0AAxImEhgmBA2OpKUaCY2OGj0TobGEF6EAL6EhKCQsAjIAMJSVACCUFAaVACWFASVetLuTKycPAK0TAtUwqQ+EltJ8kgYECCxFDgAnuzcfNq7B80mLEgW1nZUji5usm0PUjVyvVGk9WsJOoQgA)

---

<sup>* This isn't strictly true for array and tuple types; a `readonly` array or tuple is technically *wider* than a mutable version.  A mutable array is considered a subtype of a `readonly` array; the former is not known to have mutation methods like `push()` while the latter does.</sup>

Comment: I have confused now about the below example. May I know why that example does not work?
let b = (60 * 60 * 1000) as const;
Actually, the document is mentioned that const assertions can only be applied immediately on simple literal expressions. But , the inside of the parenthesis looks okay. What I am missing? Thanks.

Comment: @CihatŞaman - "'const' assertions can only be applied to references to enum members, or string, number, boolean, array, or object literals.". `60 * 60 * 1000` is not a literal, it is computed, see [the PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29510) introducing them for more details on the matter. There is an open issue on [adding math](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26382) with literal types

Comment: The two examples works without error in "Playground link to code", but says: "A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter."

Comment: Wouldn't it be worth properly typing it vs using `as const`. Consider that `const args: Readonly<{ [key: string]: number}> = {...}` is better typed than `const args = {...} as const` and achieves the same security.

Comment: I don't see how `{readonly [k: string]: number}` is "better typed" or "properly typed" compared to whatever comes out of the const assertion.  I'd need to see what the `...` is before making a judgment.  Perhaps you mean "explicitly typed" or "annotated" when you say "proper" or "better", but I don't know why explicit typing is to be preferred over inference.  In short: ‍♂️

Comment: IMO it's better to type it properly rather than adding `as const`. What I mean is `const args: [number, number] = [8, 5];`.

Comment: Just wanted to remind you guys that assertions only work in compiler time, meaning, this won't have any effect in runtime. If you need an object to be trully readonly, you can use the following:

`const myReadOnlyObject = Object.freeze({foo: 'bar'})`

(even tho ugly, this also works for arrays)

`const myReadOnlyArray = Object.freeze([1,2,3,4])`
`console.log(myReadOnlyArray.pop()) // TypeError: Cannot delete property '3' of [object Array]`

Answer (score 79):

**In short words, it lets you create fully readonly objects**, this is known as [`const assertion`](https://blog.logrocket.com/const-assertions-are-the-killer-new-typescript-feature-b73451f35802/), at your code `as const` means that the array positions values are `readonly`, here's an example of how it works:

```js
const args = [8, 5] as const;
args[0] = 3;  // throws "Cannot assign to '0' because it is a read-only   
args.push(3); // throws "Property 'push' does not exist on type 'readonly [8, 5]'"
```

You can see at the last thrown error, that `args = [8, 5] as const` is interpreted as `args: readonly [8, 5]`, that's because [the first declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) is equivalent to a [readonly tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#readonly-tuples).

**Tuples have a lot of use cases**, some examples are: [spread parameters, destructive values, etc.](https://blog.logrocket.com/use-cases-named-tuples-typescript). A general benefit is the `readonly` behaviour that is added to all its object attributes:

```js
const args = [8, 5];

// Without `as const` assert; `args` stills a constant, but you can modify its attributes
args[0] = 3;  // -- WORKS ✓
args.push(3); // -- WORKS ✓

// You are only prevented from assigning values directly to your variable
args = 7;     // -- THROWS ERROR ✖
```

There's a few exceptions for the asserts being 'fully readonly', you can check them [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#caveats-1). For more details, here's a list of other related question/answers that helped me understand the const assertion:

1. [How do I declare a read-only array tuple in TypeScript?](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions)
2. [Any difference between type assertions and the newer `as` operator in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33507791/1657465)
3. [Typescript readonly tuples](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/typescript-tuple#:%7E:text=TypeScript%20introduced%20a%20new%20data,string%20and%20tuple%20type%20variables.)

Answer (score 36):

If you were to write `const args = [8, 5]`, nothing would prevent you from then also writing `args[0] = 23` or `args.push(30)` or anything else to modify that array. All you've done is tell TS/JS that the variable named `args` points to that specific array, so you can't change what it's referencing (e.g. you can't do `args = "something else"`). You can modify the array, you just can't change what its variable is pointing to.

On the other hand, adding `as const` to a declaration now *really* makes it constant. The whole thing is read-only, so you can't modify the array at all.

---

To clarify, as pointed out in the comments:

> "really makes it constant" could imply that there is some runtime effect when there is none. At runtime, args.push(30) will still modify the array. All as const does is make it so that the TypeScript compiler will complain if it sees you doing it. – jcalz

`as const` only affects the compiler, and there is an exception to its read-only effect (see the comments). But in general, that's still the major use difference between `const` and `as const`. One is used to make *a reference* immutable and the other is used to make *what's being referenced* immutable.

Comment: Can't speak for whoever down-voted. Maybe they thought you ending statement was ambiguous (_"adding as const to a declaration now really makes it constant"_)? Not all declarations are completely readonly with `as const`: see [const assertions caveats](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#caveats-1).

Answer (score 17):

That is a `const` assertion. [Here is a handy post on them](https://blog.logrocket.com/const-assertions-are-the-killer-new-typescript-feature-b73451f35802/), and [here is the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions).

> When we construct new literal expressions with const assertions, we can signal to the language that
>
> - no literal types in that expression should be widened (e.g. no going from "hello" to string)
> - object literals get readonly properties
> - array literals become readonly tuples

With `const args = [8, 5] as const;`, the third bullet applies, and tsc will understand it to mean:

```
// Type: readonly [8, 5]
const args = [8, 5] as const;

// Ok
args[0];
args[1];

// Error: Tuple type 'readonly [8, 5]' of length '2' has no element at index '2'.
args[2];
```

Without the assertion:

```
// Type: number[]
const args = [8, 5];

// Ok
args[0];
args[1];

// Also Ok.
args[2];
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I can't seem to find it in the documentation, but how come the 'length' property is accessible even with const assertion, say `args['length']`.

Comment: @The.Wolfgang.Grimmer Because technically tuple types are still arrays.

Comment: I see, and it seems like `length` is the only property in an array object. Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 17):

`as const` when applied to an object or array it makes them immutable (i.e. making them read-only). For other literals it prevents type widening.

```
const args = [8, 5] as const;

args[0] = 10; ❌ Cannot assign to '0' because it is a read-only property.
```

Few other advantages **:**

- You can catch bugs at compile-time without running the program if you don't cast to a different type.
- The compiler will not allow you to reassign properties of nested objects.

Answer (score 8):

Amazing answers have been added already, just wanted to drop another `as const` example that might be useful to some, and is a bit different from the examples in other answers:

```
type Status = "success" | "danger"

function foo(status: Status){
  console.log({ status });
}

const status = "success";

// ❌ Error: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Status'.
foo(status);
```

The reason it's not working is when typescript sees `const status = "success"`, it infers the type of the status variable as a string, while the status parameter of the `foo` function is not of a type as broad as "string", it's very much more specific, it either has to be "success" or "danger".

To fix this you have two ways:

```
// #1: Call foo with "success" directly and TypeScript is smart enough to accept it:
foo("success");
// #2: Solution #1 however is not always useable, e.g., when status is received  from
// somewhere else, in that case, we have no other options but using a variable for it
// That's how it can be done using a variable:
foo("success" as const);
```

Actually, it's not different from what @jcalz said in their great answer:

> A const assertion tells the compiler to infer the narrowest or most specific type it can for an expression.