# SendGrid client TypeScript Error: HttpMethod

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I have:

```
import sendgridClient from '@sendgrid/client'
sendgridClient.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

const sendgridRequest = {
        method: 'PUT',
        url: '/v3/marketing/contacts',
        body: {
            list_ids: [myId],
            contacts: [
                {
                    email: req.body.email,
                    custom_fields: {
                        [myFieldId]: 'in_free_trial'
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    };


await sendgridClient.request(sendgridRequest);
```

But my TypeScript language server gives me an error about `sendgridRequest`:

```
Argument of type '{ method: string; url: string; body: { list_ids: string[]; contacts: { email: any; custom_fields: { e5_T: string; }; }[]; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ClientRequest'.
  Types of property 'method' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'HttpMethod'.
```

Is there some way to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`method: 'PUT'` in your object is being inferred as `string`, but it's expecting specific strings like `"PUT" | "GET" | "POST"`. This because it has no specific type to try to match, and by default specific strings are just inferred as `string`.

You can probably fix this by passing your object directly to the function. This casts the object as the right type because it's checked against what that function accepts:

```
await sendgridClient.request({
    method: 'PUT',
    url: '/v3/marketing/contacts',
    body: {
        list_ids: [myId],
        contacts: [
            {
                email: req.body.email,
                custom_fields: {
                    [myFieldId]: 'in_free_trial'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

Or you can give your intermediate variable the correct type imported from the sendgrid module.

```
import sendgridClient, { ClientRequest } from '@sendgrid/client'

const sendgridRequest: ClientRequest  = { /* ... */ }
await sendgridClient.request(sendgridRequest);
```

---

I wasn't able to test this because this module doesn't seem import into the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAZwKYDsAmBzKw0GEA2wqMANHAN5wFEowBKSAjgK5ILwC+cAZlBCHADkAAWTosOAPQBjQsUEAoMZmx45tAHTIYAQTDAA0kgCeACjB9pbBBtQA3DQGUAogDkAIgHE6ASXcB9HQAFH38DZwBNAEoAbgUFaQgUdkRUFRwGFjYYAC4qdXomVhS4AF4KBTgquBAkGAALCDQ8wSCAVQAVQRJK6uYofBbJOwBmSRAAQygAazrgFAwZJJgJ6RgEbt6qgCMm4zzyLeqqwnZ-HAQ8gG0QYx80AF0e4+PE2lX166OX6sOf-+qSEmwEGcCgTA0uzQxlswPwzwB-2kzHY-H83CI+DQlwqiLxcBuxgAYpi0PcHi15ujwUh-DBsBN8Ip8S8ON9-myAQ8jmyOHF4hMAO4TYDwZQSNQ0GAacFZdimcWqTLFGCxIA) but I *think* that should work.

Answer (score 7):

Another way of doing this in the absence of the original types:

```
method: 'PUT' as const,
```

A string is not assignable to HttpMethod, but the string literal 'PUT' is!

More details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66993654/91713