# Array of const type, no more no less values

Tags: typescript

A library I'm using exports a type like this:

```
type Pet = 'dog' | 'cat' | 'rat';
```

I want to now make a dropdown that has all these values in my UI. I am not able to enumerate this const type. So I thought to  make an array of these values and type it such that it must have exactly one of each const in the type `Pet` but can't figure this out.

I tried the following but it doesn't cause error when more keys are added to `Pet`. I want typescript to fail on build when I update the lib and the lib decided to add more consts.

```
type Pet = 'dog' | 'cat' | 'rat';

const pets: Pet[] = ['dog', 'dog']; // this should error as its missing "cat" and "rat". and also it has "dog" twice.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](https://ja.nsommer.dk/articles/type-checked-unique-arrays.html) if you use `TypeScript 4.1` or later you can do like this:

```
type UniqueArray<T> =
  T extends readonly [infer X, ...infer Rest]
    ? InArray<Rest, X> extends true
      ? ['Encountered value with duplicates:', X]
      : readonly [X, ...UniqueArray<Rest>]
    : T

type InArray<T, X> =
  T extends readonly [X, ...infer _Rest]
    ? true
    : T extends readonly [X]
      ? true
      : T extends readonly [infer _, ...infer Rest]
        ? InArray<Rest, X>
        : false


const data = ['dog', 'cat' , 'rat'] as const
const uniqueData: UniqueArray<typeof data> = data

const pets: UniqueArray <typeof data> = ['dog', 'dog']; // this should error as its missing "cat" and "rat". and also it has "dog" twice.
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwI4FcIEEBOmCGIA8AKgHxQC8AUFFIVBAB7ARwAmAzlJhDiwPZwAbEFADaCOADMImKAA0ANFAB0K8VJkAlCG2ABdKtSgB%20KAEk4WXAS07Fs0gyasOwTGgOHjogOQBROADGvChwTFwsUABuOAJoUADuCMAAFlAsKGACCAE4TGwAXN52%20p7U%20ZzcfILCIgrKKvDIaJZ4%20DbAxCWG5YQUFKCQZhbYrYR2pJTUtI7M7BU8-EKidSpKatJQAPrtXdQmru6ePXSMsxxcC9XLu4b7bhAe3TQnTnMXVUtikhubiqvrmm0ekenhM5ha1iB4xBTwkMTYDz6QTgOjSuRw5B8fAA5kUoN4csBvFBFN5cETdFAcBxkToKLTgFAQk0IAARdHlRqoDAjAgDCC8CRo4A4CbCnBI-ioyDAAqwRDciFQfD8wXisUibw4vFa3i43QAbigAHpjVAUggOGxksEBBFpJheDJqVAkhwALaWtjibFQABEhL9VNY-vJfqUwYi8N4rsZyRdfpxQeAiQCECUfSAA) is working code.

Comment: Wow this is really very cool! Thank you for this!!

Comment: But actually can we make it such that `const data` is `type Pets = 'dog' | 'cat' | 'rat'` Im trying to ensure that the array has each key present in this type.

Comment: When I change it to: `type Pet = 'dog' | 'cat' | 'rat' | 'mouse'; const data = ['dog', 'cat' , 'rat'] as Pet[];` its not erroring when `data` does not include `"mouse"`

Comment: You need to define `const` variable

Comment: Thanks can you show example please, I'm not able to figure it out.

Comment: The important thing in that code is `as const` . see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66993264/what-does-the-as-const-mean-in-typescript-and-what-is-its-use-case)

Comment: Thanks I understand const now. But my problem is `Pets` is a type I don't have control over. I want to make an array that has every const from `Pets` in it. I'm struggling with this.