# Why can't I send prop as an object property in React component (typescript)?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I have a constant:

```
export const LIST_OF_TYPES = {
  TYPE1: 'type1',
  TYPE2: 'type2',
};
```

In the component, I define the `type` as follows:

```
export type IExampleComponentType = 'type1' | 'type2';

interface IExampleComponentProps {
  type: IExampleComponentType;
}

const ExampleComponent: React.FC<IExampleComponentProps> = ({
  type,
}) => {
...
```

When I try to send a prop to a component like this:

```
<ExampleComponent type={LIST_OF_TYPES.TYPE1} />
```

i see an error for prop `type` like this:

> TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'IExampleComponentType'.

> The expected type comes from property 'type' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IExampleComponentProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'

What's wrong? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare `LIST_OF_TYPES` like this, it's type is automatically derived as `{ TYPE1: string; TYPE2: string }`, since Typescript supposes you can write some other values into `LIST_OF_TYPES`'s properties in the future. You can prevent this using `as const` cast:

```js
const LIST_OF_TYPES = {
  ...
} as const;

// also you can now declare IExampleComponentType like this:
type IExampleComponentType = (typeof LIST_OF_TYPES)[keyof typeof LIST_OF_TYPES];
```

Also you may use a `enum` here (and it seems like you need one):

```js
enum LIST_OF_TYPES {
  TYPE1 = 'type1',
  TYPE2 = 'type2',
}

// also now IExampleComponentType can be replaced with just LIST_OF_TYPES
```

Check it out at the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAMgSQMoBUD6B5AYmlBNABQFEk0BGGAXhgG8AoGGfYsgLhgHIoBPABwFMyHADQMmhIgCZ2XPv0ki6AXzp0A9GpjQATgEswAczo8BMKP2gVqJ-iABm8ZOmy4JpMgDpmRMqtCRYRFRMHG9SSSpaMW82ThshUUZvaTi5BVElGABDCBh-aFUNGAAieOLjOTMLKAjrOXtHYJcwtEkvCV86fjAAVwBbRudQtzQAZiikjsjZAQToiVrUgXTlQs0goddiUlH2lgrTc2hxuoEGjZCtkjG9nyA)

Comment: Wouldn't it be: `type IExampleComponentType = (typeof LIST_OF_TYPES)[keyof typeof LIST_OF_TYPES]` to extract the types from the ***values*** of `LIST_OF_TYPES`?

Comment: Sure it will, my bad

Answer (score 1):

The type of `LIST_OF_TYPES` is:

```
{
    TYPE1: string;
    TYPE2: string;
}
```

if you declare `LIST_OF_TYPES` with the `as const` modifier:

```
export const LIST_OF_TYPES = {
  TYPE1: 'type1',
  TYPE2: 'type2',
} as const;
```

its type will, instead be:

```
{
    readonly TYPE1: "type1";
    readonly TYPE2: "type2";
}
```

Which is, I believe, what you're looking for.

Further reading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66993654/14357

Answer (score 1):

A literal is a more concrete sub-type of a collective type. What this means is that "Hello World" is a string, but a string is not "Hello World" inside the type system. - Ts Doc

Typescript will infer string literal types only when you assign it to a const.

Understand it by example

```
const LIST_OF_TYPES = {
  TYPE1: 'type1',
  TYPE2: 'type2'
};

//string literal
type IExampleType = 'type1' | 'type2';

function myFunction(value: IExampleType) {
  console.log(value);
}

//This will not work
myFunction(LIST_OF_TYPES.TYPE1);
```

Type Error: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of
type IExampleType'.

```
//This will work
const myValue = 'type1';
myFunction(myValue);
```