# Typescript type check a methods second parameter based on first choice

Tags: typescript

Take a look at the `request` methods' params in this class

```
export type SDKmodules =  'orders' |'pricing' |'catalogV2' |'catalog' |'prodType' |'reports' |'listings';

export class SellerAPI {
    request(mod: SDKmodules, method: string, params: any = {}) {
        return this.http.get<any>( `/sp-sdk/${mod}/${method}`, { params });
    }
}
```

I am trying to type the `request` parameters based on the chosen module. Each module is a *class*. Here is a simplified down view.

```
{
    orders: ['getOrder', 'getOrderExt', 'getOrderItems', 'saveOrders'],
    pricing: ["getCompetitivePricing", "getItemOffers", "getListingOffers", "getPricing"],
    catalogV2: ["getCatalogItem", "searchCatalogItems", "getCatalogProdType"],
}
```

so if the module choice was `orders` then the only acceptable `method` would be...

`'getOrder', 'getOrderExt', 'getOrderItems', 'saveOrders'`

**Im looking for the most appropriate way to type this method. *even if it means undoing any part of the sample code above*.**

Here are somethings i think might work.

- Multiple overloads for the request method
- Because all of the "modules" *(the parameter)* are class objects. Is there a way to use the modules them selves to type this method?

Im pretty new to typescript. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTE: This question answers the original revision of the question

Here's one way that can be achieved by extracting the type from the `moduleMethods` constant (defined below), which has a [`const` assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66993264/what-does-the-as-const-mean-in-typescript-and-what-is-its-use-case):

```
export type SDKmodules = 'orders' | 'pricing' | 'catalogV2'; 
    // | 'catalog' | 'prodType' | 'reports' | 'listings';

const moduleMethods = {
    orders: [
        'getOrder', 'getOrderExt', 'getOrderItems', 'saveOrders'],
    pricing: [
        "getCompetitivePricing", "getItemOffers", "getListingOffers", "getPricing"],
    catalogV2: [
        "getCatalogItem", "searchCatalogItems", "getCatalogProdType"],
} as const;

type OrderType<T extends SDKmodules> = (typeof moduleMethods)[T][number]

export class SellerAPI {
    request<T extends SDKmodules>(mod: T, method: OrderType<T>, params: any = {}) {
        return console.log(`/sp-sdk/${mod}/${method}`, { params });
    }
}

const api = new SellerAPI()
api.request("orders", "getOrderItems")
```

You could even take it one step further, and infer the type of `SDKModules` from `moduleMethods` with:

```
type SDKModules = keyof typeof moduleMethods;
```

so that the `moduleMethods` object becomes your one source of truth.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTCmA8AcHsCcBcAE8CelSIMoBEDSBbaAEwFcAbUAZ0QF5EByOI0WS+xAHwclgEsBjXgDsA5uy71+AQ3hSy0EQDUATPQDciEJwbTZ8sdvo9iAFTShxDWKBgI2hsr0rxhItmoBQH-tCHPEhKQUALKg8AAWxNR0AN4eiAmITCyUAFyIANr0ImEA8rDMsPQANAw58PmFAKLg8CVleQUsAJLwoPhspfSUUgBuoJUp9AC6xfGJPAKu6RkAROUAwtD46C4u-QAKfIKis6XzYa3tuQBmJyl7iAfwADJOLqKn56yX11tTu6PjCbpyCioza4LGR-ERHfCvSigKSwfjhYF6BTgyivRYg-RbUzmWZfAC+iCk1B8fngng8EFsSFQ6CweEC5CotEQAGtQChoCdkOYOQFiAzQhEomTqRgBZEiJRTsE+RQADwmRAQNpCCW0ggyqgAPiZAAoRTz6SEwuLKABKDImYYZIQkfAAIxYwy8FLgSH4ZEJ1EwoDIFFgAEENs1EHFEohrABHEhUeDyxW1UAqr10jWUTU6wLpEylfDG4jpMVRKUa+Wa0qQGFSDrpKRCFBMmK400h75h8NhEiwISIYmUaAUAB0+h1AANgJRIABaShEZnAAAkMUCuIXS7zRFxI9KMUQFdgVeoTc8YdxHlP3l8-ikkF4TKEoAA7lgfX7A80daaPNfeAPI9HnDqszJC8+zlIMsDIrMppAA)

Comment: Wow thank you for the time you spent writing that. I updated my question to include my version of "moduleMethods" instead of the other sample object. Im working in a mono repo. We cant import moduleMethods into the frontend cause its nodejs only. Do you know how to import it for type use only? if there is a way then i can use the ideal version of ur answer. Im open to changing everything to satisfy one place maintenance for this method

Comment: Or instead do you recommend that i just maintain module methods as a simple object like the one in your answer? That doesnt sound 'wrong'.