# TypeScript: Infer literal type of already defined type

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

Not sure if this is possible or to best describe this, but I need to infer the literal type of a type that's already defined by another type/interface.

For example, I've got an object that adheres to a certain interface:

```
interface MyObject {
    foo: string | number;
    bar: string[];
}
const MY_OBJECT: MyObject = {
    foo: 123,
    bar: ["abc", "def"],
};
```

Now, what I'd like to know is the type literal of `MY_OBJECT`, by doing something like this:

```
type MyObjectLiteral = Infer<typeof MY_OBJECT>;
```

That should make `MyObjectLiteral`: `{ foo: 123, bar: ["abc", "def"] }`

The question is how to define `type Infer<T>` to return the inferred type of `T`.

Any help or clarification would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really possible with types alone. A soon as you assign a value to a type that is wider than what could be inferred, you lose that type information.

But you can always treat a more narrow type as the wider type that includes it. Which means you can always go the *other* direction.

---

You could simply declare your object [`as const`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66993264/what-does-the-as-const-mean-in-typescript-and-what-is-its-use-case) and then use it anywhere that accepts a `MyObject` type.

```
interface MyObject {
    foo: string | number;
    bar: readonly string[];
}

const myObject = { foo: 123, bar: ["abc", "def"] } as const
const barZero = myObject.bar[0] // type: "abc"

const myObjectWide: MyObject = myObject // works
const barWideZero = myObjectWide.bar[0] // type: string
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=56&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DyAjAVhBMZAbwChkLkYB7agLmQGcwpQBzZAH2RAFcBbbNADc5StjhQGUCHAAm1EABt0TFuwDaAXVEBfUqQSLmyfljwEiAXhJVaDAIwAmAMwAaZBKnINAIjjYCL4evnIQML5ayLrIcIzIRiDMhsZEXgBa0NTINmY4+IQAdF4aAAxRAPQVyGDoAA4QDP6BvgaJJnkWhADqwGEMGPmWOabmBURVyADu1FAA1owpSWmSvWGZUNm5Y5ZrEMWSZZXVtQ0MzKwgbEA)

---

Or if you want to constrain the construction of `myObject` you can use a function to capture the exact subtype, and return it.

For example:

```
interface MyObject {
    foo: string | number;
    bar: readonly string[];
}

function makeObj<T extends MyObject>(myObject: T): T {
    return myObject
}

const myBadObject = makeObj({ bad: true } as const)
// Argument of type '{ readonly bad: true; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MyObject'.
//  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'bad' does not exist in type 'MyObject'.(2345)

const myObject = makeObj({ foo: 123, bar: ["abc", "def"] } as const)
const barZero = myObject.bar[0] // type: "abc"

const myObjectWide: MyObject = myObject // works
const barWideZero = myObjectWide.bar[0] // type: string
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DyAjAVhBMZAbwChkLkYB7agLmQGcwpQBzZAH2RAFcBbbNADc5StjhQGUCHAAm1EABt0TFuwDaAXVEBfUqRi8QhYIuT84Aawg5cAHgAqyCAA9IIOYzRY8BMAB8ABT8vviEDI4AlJEkYhQyYLxQIBZh-qT6pAD02cgScsjUfoTI6MAQSl7IcMhg6AAOKNBQ1FDIABbQEKQIisxpAELydv7IALwW1rZ4QcT58gwsvCi6Nd59IMxRBpsDoaOlk5Y2dnNUtAwAjABMAMwANAtSyBoARHDYCG9Pb3IQMDeWmQazgG36YB2eyIEigAC1oNQJmlDmAAHSwjQABmBuTqjQgDA+XzeuwhKJKYAA6sB-gwMKjkQdKcg8QB3NpWRi9cmwmn-BGtJnpQj8iAYyTY3F5epNBjMVggNhAA)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! Unfortunately I'm restricted to a type-based solution only for the generics-paradox I'm trying to solve, so I guess I have to think of another solution for now.