# How to create a Typescript type based on the keys/values of a dictionary?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, mapped-types

Is there a way to automatically generate a type based on a dictionary value? E.g. given this dictionary of constant values:

```
export const SHIPMETHODS: OptionsMap<UpsShipMethodOption> = {
    'UPS': 'GND',
    'UPS AIR2': '2DA',
    'UPS 3DAY SELECT': '3DS'
}
```

Is there a way to automatically generate a type like this, without having to duplicate everything?

```
export type ShipMethodOptionMap = {
    'UPS': 'GND',
    'UPS AIR2': '2DA',
    'UPS 3DAY SELECT': '3DS'
}
```

Unfortunately keyof doesn't seem to work since it's an object and not a type, so this doesn't work:

```
export type UpsShipMethodOption = keyof SHIPMETHODS // Doesn't work
```

I also tried using mapped types with a predeclared union type of the keys, but it doesn't work either:

```
/* 
  Type 'KeyOptions' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
  Type 'KeyOptions' is not assignable to type 'symbol'.ts(2322)
*/
export type OptionsMap<KeyOptions> = {
    readonly [Property in KeyOptions]: string;
}

export const SHIPMETHODS: OptionsMap<UpsShipMethodOption> = {
    'UPS': 'GND',
    'UPS AIR2': '2DA',
    'UPS 3DAY SELECT': '3DS'
}
export type UpsShipMethodOption = 'UPS' | 'UPS AIR2' | 'UPS 3DAY SELECT'
```

I have a bunch of such dictionaries, and most of them are quite large (30+ keys). Duplicating the dictionary into a type everywhere would make it a pain to maintain in case the values change, so any help with this would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just want the `typeof` operator. It simply gets the type of a value.

```
const SHIPMETHODS = {
    'UPS': 'GND',
    'UPS AIR2': '2DA',
    'UPS 3DAY SELECT': '3DS'
} as const // as const is important.

type ShipMethodOptionMap = typeof SHIPMETHODS 
/*
type ShipMethodOptionMap = {
    readonly UPS: "GND";
    readonly 'UPS AIR2': "2DA";
    readonly 'UPS 3DAY SELECT': "3DS";
}
*/

type UpsShipMethodOption = keyof ShipMethodOptionMap
// type UpsShipMethodOption = "UPS" | "UPS AIR2" | "UPS 3DAY SELECT"
```

Just note [the `as const` on your object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66993264/what-does-the-as-const-mean-in-typescript-and-what-is-its-use-case) which allows typescript to infer the string literals so they can become part of the type.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=69&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAygCQJIAUCyBRAKgg8gEThgF4YBvAWACgZaYByAVRTnoC4GBxAOX3oBpqdBsyIBBJACUATOwbT8YgULpMWMAMyKAmvAwAZDAGEsc+ltbUAvjACGEGKEhRq1KAE8ADgFN4ACwBLTzRvKD8QABNcTygA8DRbTxIYDx8QADN4ZHRsPEIYagB6ACo3L184QODQ8KiYuLAEpNJKGjoAJ29bCPAAG3cYUQ4AIh58YYBuFVpO7r6BtXEpWRGFMUnpmFmesH6RdS0xXTgDY1MRiw2qK2piwtcqVN9GTwhKoJCwyOjY8GSAa287gy-g+NW+9XiiSKhRS5UGr3e1S+dV+YGSw1EwxgAB8YJj1BIZNi8QSiIdjqcTMMgA)

Comment: Ah! This is perfect, thank you! :)