# TypeScript: Difference between `const myVar` and `const myVar as const` for literals

Tags: typescript, generics, types, constants, literals

My question is pretty simple here, I would like to understand the the relationship between casting a literal with `as const` and the infer of a generics.

Here a sample repro:

```
declare global {
    interface String {
        // @ts-expect-error Simulate skipLibCheck
        toUpperCase<T>(this: T): Uppercase<T>;
    }
}
export {};

const strA = "mylowercasedstring"; // typed as "mylowercasedstring" (literal)
const strB = "mylowercasedstring" as const; // also typed as "mylowercasedstring" (literal)
const resultA = strA.toUpperCase(); // typed as string
const resultB = strB.toUpperCase(); // typed as "MYLOWERCASEDSTRING" (literal)
// why?
```

Why `resultA` is not properly infered like `resultB`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the "as const" mean in TypeScript and what is its use case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66993264/what-does-the-as-const-mean-in-typescript-and-what-is-its-use-case)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion !
But no because I already know the assertion / readonly part of a `as const` cast. My question is more about how it's linked with infering into the compiler.

Comment: I don't have the answer but try `const toUpper = <T extends string>(x: T) => x.toUpperCase()` on `strA`... It's kind of funny. I was first assuming that, because you call a method on a string, JS is boxing it in a String object before running the function which widens the type to `string`, as if you were calling `String` on it, and TS would somehow treat `as const` differently but it's not what is happening, and calling `String` on `strB` confirms that

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the answer! Yeah, I could do that, I could also remove the `skipLibCheck` and type `toUpperCase` like you did `toUpperCase<T extends string>(...)` ;
But I don't try to find a way make it work, as I already know that ; I try to understand why it **doesn't** work :p