# TypeScript error when using a template literal for bracket notation

Tags: typescript

I have an object named `endpoints` that has various methods:

```
const endpoints = {
  async getProfilePhoto(photoFile: File) {
    return await updateProfilePhotoTask.perform(photoFile);
  },
};
```

And I'm using this function to access the methods. It takes a string argument, which is used to build a template literal, and then accesses the method using bracket notation:

```
export const useApiTask = (
  endpointName: string,
) => {
  //const apiActionName = 'getProfilePhoto'; // When defined as a string it works
  const apiActionName = `get${endpointName}`; // But when using template literals I get a TypeScript error
  const endpointHandler = endpoints[apiActionName]; // The TypeScript error shows here
}
```

But using a template literal creates this TypeScript error on `endpointHandler = endpoints[apiActionName]`:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ getProfilePhoto(photoFile: File): Promise<string | undefined>; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ getProfilePhoto(photoFile: File): Promise<string | undefined>; }'. ts(7053)
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with this code. First `endpointName` can't be any `string`,  it must be a valid key of `endpoints` (minus the `get` prefix). So we need to have a narrower type for that. The second issue is that even if `endpointName` is a union of valid keys, the literal operation will still produce `string` unless we tell TypeScript we want a narrower type using an `as const`:

```
const endpoints = {
  async getProfilePhoto(photoFile: File) {
    return await Promise.resolve();
  },
  async getProfile(photoFile: File) {
    return await Promise.resolve();
  },
};

export const useApiTask = (
  endpointName: 'ProfilePhoto' | 'Profile', // Union of posibilities
) => {
  const apiActionName = `get${endpointName}` as const;  // Make sure the type info is preserverd
  const endpointHandler = endpoints[apiActionName]; 
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmAJgBxASzFCMC8MDeAUDDAIYQCeYwMA5nFAAoBOIAZmgDZyMAWIUEAApk-QQDEucAFwxJ3AJQFiJGMwYBXZmDIB3UmlgsQAWzQQ4AOnUQQnAG5whCgNwqAvgBoV5KjXpMrBzcImIg8jJyUkpEqmqa2noGRqxmFtZwtg5Orh7e7m6EcAAeqMywoJCwGhYAgshoACrkANa4MEIqCCjomABypCaRAOTGwTxhwzAAPjCjQVLDnjAA9CswAKpgaOAw7DCoEGgARlyGaJmESjgAfMokldBkDbXAUDtgA0PtAAYBACT4bqoDBQL5wdw-MjYR5QFwkNYwACypBacBgEC06KgvGxFGQ6IwbBAMHMBxscGYjmYiBUsPgSBBmAAEqQkNxmO1gb0sABtUgvN4fcEAXXhhHcQA)

You could also use a conditional type to extract the union of names to avoid repeating the names:

```
type EndpointNames = keyof typeof endpoints extends `get${infer Name}` ? Name : never
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmAJgBxASzFCMC8MDeAUDDAIYQCeYwMA5nFAAoBOIAZmgDZyMAWIUEAApk-QQDEucAFwxJ3AJQFiJGMwYBXZmDIB3UmlgsQAWzQQ4AOnUQQnAG5whCgNwqAvgBoV5KjXpMrBzcImIg8jJyUkpEqmqa2noGRqxmFtZwtg5Orh7e7m6EUBTIcDAAokioGFAAcqQmmbgwANZwFOwwxaWdCCjomNhwAB5QfdgABgEAJPgYbHDMMPWN7hMwAPzLDWWyYHCOzISEI6jMsKCQsBoWAILIaAAq5C3NQip91ZgrkZX9NT8IIQlDgAHzKEiXaBkB63YBQNDgH7NKYMWafAZ1HZrMjYKFQFwkAD0RJgAFlSG0YBAtGUoLw6SUyvMQDBzDBkDZFodECp8fAqpiABKkJDcJZ4DE1CAAbVIsPhiLAPwAuoTCO4gA)

Comment: Thanks, this is is great and has worked in my own code. But I have never seen `as const` before so I was a little confused. If anyone else needs more reading check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66993264/what-does-the-as-const-mean-in-typescript-and-what-is-its-use-case

Answer (score 1):

This error is occurring because the keys of `typeof endpoints` are not `string`, but rather the literal string `"getProfilePhoto"` (in your example).

To address this, you can use a clever trick, [template literal inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#inference-with-template-literals), to derive the type of the names of the keys in your `endpoints` which match the pattern of "strings beginning with `get`", and then use the type on your `endpointName` parameter, like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gVwA7CgxAAUYkAzASwhIAskMkAVKNAawC54BveXEGOSQwAtvAAUVGlwBi1EAEoupJCMpoQAHmwo2KJAHcUAPgDc8AL6mAUNeTosIFMFxJKKDGngBeHtfjwrACeKGDwAOYgGCpSdAxI4rj0jHLS8KmKfgEBcBjYMCiBBlCUWHgERDHyxMnMrGwAdPyCwiKJtRkKNgEWADT+EVEAggBy2CIARgLiClnZufmFALKEtA0wUM6qM92W-QGRGEy06iq4XADktCAQEEgX-Va2APTP8Mfq8FPIIiBeAERVGg1eL-eAAH3g-1G4ymMH+1gwQX48AAos5XO4MDIdGAMJRUCMoL80KQQFQAB4gYAAISCAHEoj54Ej+BR4E4XG4PF4QBSiM4vO5yAJ3vAAPzwNggILs3gAbQGAGl4O4pTL2UxAl4VXyBcAvAADQ4AEm4wtFRN+FkNEoGASY8qVAF0OfzOV5xA1vbhYMS0FxNkFZt5jIEUEEJfArQguCgQAA3AT2+BxxPJ51cHR6QwocwWVPweNJmA2ax81wwLD2TA4DRDXCUFjsZniTmYjwxrjorlYnGhfGE4l-MmU6l0xkYENh7gDGuODHcjAACU2wBoMGZ7aXaHlxqiZu3WJjNudNgs1iAA)

```ts
declare const updateProfilePhotoTask: { perform (file: File): Promise<unknown>; };

const endpoints = {
  async getProfilePhoto(photoFile: File) {
    return await updateProfilePhotoTask.perform(photoFile);
  },
  getANumber() {
    return Math.random();
  },
  getThisProp: 'hello',
};

// This becomes "ProfilePhoto" | "ANumber"
type EndpointFunctionNamesPrefixedByGet = typeof endpoints extends infer T ? keyof { [
  K in keyof T as K extends `get${infer Name}` ?
    T[K] extends (...params: any) => any ? Name : never
    : never
]: unknown; } : never;

export const useApiTask = (endpointName: EndpointFunctionNamesPrefixedByGet) => {
  const endpointHandler = endpoints[`get${endpointName}`];
}
```