# How to generate value from type?

Tags: typescript

Given the following TypeScript type:

```js
type options = 
    | {label: "a", fields: Array<Object>}
    | {label: "b", fields: Array<Object>}
    | {label: "c", fields: Array<Object>}
;
```

Is there a way to use the `options` type to generate a value (e.g. `["a", "b", "c"]`) that can be used at runtime?

If so, how can `["a", "b", "c"]` be generated from the `options` type?

Comment: The types don't exist at runtime, they're erased in compilation.

Comment: I can accept that as an answer if there's no way to generate values from types.

Comment: Are you amenable to a solution that reverses the problem to create a type from a value?  Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w1632N). This has the benefit of being at least possible.

Comment: That's very interesting, but it sounds like the answer to this question is that there's no way to do what I outlined above. That's totally fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have suggested - you can't generate a value from a type, as the concepts of types don't exist at runtime.

What you could do instead, is generate your types from values. The [`typeof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) operation is helpful here

```
const labels = ["a", "b", "c"] as const; 

type PossibleValues = typeof labels[number]; // type PossibleValues = "a" | "b" | "c"
type Options = {label: PossibleValues, fields: Array<unknown>}; 


const a: Options = {
    label: "a", 
    fields: [], 
}

const notRight: Options = {
    label: "fobar", //Type '"fobar"' is not assignable to type '"a" | "b" | "c"'.(2322)
    fields: [], 
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBANgQwEYFM4RgXhgbQEQJ4A0MeSxpweAujAhqJFANwwBQbUAngA4owAFEBAgBLJHBQA1BHACuKDNm58QAM3jI0EHGDkBbVACdqrAPRmYK-kJHjJM+YqylCMAD6lyHynk69+AHkeKFFwJRgAb0RUOAAuQWExCWlZBQgSNVE0ABMIBIBBIyMELgAeOTAAazAQAHcwAD4AX1YONkZoOgTg0PCXSLYYYc1YhIIKIZGs3PzcahI2Zo5O2FqoACVRAHMACygekLDIAanhmLRxtRAkBCMKCwAVAJgAcjxr2-vXmFEMdbodm2YGQkisICsL3ebk8ZDwPjwVFeADoABQA)

What's happening here:

```
const labels = ["a", "b", "c"] as const;
```

We need to use the [`as const` assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66993264/what-does-the-as-const-mean-in-typescript-and-what-is-its-use-case) here to tell typescript that labels isn't an array of any ol' strings, it's an array of *these specific* strings.

```
type PossibleValues = typeof labels[number];
```

We are doing two things here:

- First we are saying 'what is the type of `labels`', which is `Array<"a" | "b" | "c">`.
- Next we say, 'what is the type of of the things accessible by `number`'. (ie. what are all the possible types of the arrays contents. Remember an array also has prototype functions like .forEach etc).

Now we can create our Options type.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if I understand the question correctly but if I do could you do

```
enum myValues {
    A = 'a',
    B = 'b',
    C = 'c'
}

interface myInterface {
    label : myValues;
    fields : Array<any>
}

// then for an array you could use Object.values

Object.values( myValues ).foreach( ( item ) => {
   console.log( item );
}

// Will print out 
// "a"
// "b"
// "c"

let objArray : Array<myInterface> = new Array<myInterface>();
Object.values.foreach( ( item ) => {
   let myObj : myInterface = {
       label: item
       fields: new Array<any>()
   }
   objArray.push(myObj);
}

// This will give you an array of all the objects as described in your question
// {label: "a", fields: Array<Object>},
// {label: "b", fields: Array<Object>},
// {label: "c", fields: Array<Object>}
```