# Typescript const with custom type as const

Tags: javascript, typescript

We have:

```js
type test = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
};

const arr: test[] = [{ id: 1, name: 'test-1' }, { id: 2, name: 'test-2' }];
```

And I want to create a type from an array of objects:

```js
type other = typeof arr[number]['name'];

const another: other = 'test-1'; // Should be 'test-1' | 'test-2' but it's string
```

If I remove the custom type of `arr` and use const assertion:

```js
const arr = [{ id: 1, name: 'test-1' }, { id: 2, name: 'test-2' }] as const;

type other = typeof arr[number]['name'];

const another: other = 'test-2'; // Works!
```

It'll work, but I want to have a type for my `arr` too.

How can I create something like this:

```js
type test = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
};

const arr: test[] = [
  { id: 1, name: 'test-1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'test-2' }
] as const;

type other = typeof arr[number]['name'];

const another: other = 'test-1';
```

I tried to use `ReadonlyArray<test>` but no luck!

Comment: Do you want `other` to be `'test-1' | 'test-2'` or `string`? Do you want `arr` to contain only those two elements, or to contain any objects of type `test` with arbitrary `string` names?

Comment: @Bergi I want `other` to be `test-1' | 'test-2` and want `arr` to only contain those two elements.

Comment: Then you should just use `as const`, and not declare `arr: test[]`. It's not clear what you mean by "*I want to have a type for my `arr` too.*", or *why* you'd want that. The `arr` variable always has a type.

Comment: I want to have type for my `arr`, how can I do that?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66993654/12162258) answer might be useful in understanding why `as const` accomplishes what you want.

Comment: So there is no way to declare type for my `arr`?

Comment: Can you articulate *why* you want to declare the type of `arr`?  What is the use case driving the question?  You shouldn't need to do it, and if you do it, it will be like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N7OMRN), which is going to be annoying.  So people are asking you *why* you think you need this.