# How can I achieve a union type of object values in typescript

Tags: typescript

```
const obj = {
    a: 122,
    b: 456,
    c: '123',
};

// Keys = "a" | "b" | "c"
type Keys = keyof typeof obj;
// Values = string | number"
type Values = typeof obj[Keys];
const a: Values = '1234'; // => should throw an error
```

I am looking for a way to get a union type like so: `123 | 456 | '123'`

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a combination of `as const`, `keyof` and `typeof` you can achieve this. With `as consts` the object becomes immutable and Typescript is able to extract the values using the keys.

```
const obj = {
  a: 122,
  b: 456,
  c: '123',
} as const // use 'as const' here

// Keys = "a" | "b" | "c"
type Keys = keyof typeof obj
// Values = 122 | 456 | "123"
type Values = typeof obj[Keys]
```

---

This is a nice explanation of the `as const` functionality btw: [What does the "as const" mean in TypeScript and what is its use case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66993264/what-does-the-as-const-mean-in-typescript-and-what-is-its-use-case)