# I cannot set defaultProps with PartialType in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I would like to pass to a Provider an orientation value (horizontal or vertical), but I have it declared as optional in case the user does not want to pass it.

Through defaultProps I am trying to do the same that I could do with {orientation = 'horizontal'} but it's not working correctly.

This gives me an error where it says orientation can be undefined.

```
export interface TabsProps extends Props {
    active: string;
    color?: DanaColor;
    orientation?: 'horizontal' | 'vertical';
    onTabChange: (tabKey: string) => void;
    children: ReactElement | ReactElement[];
}

const defaultProps: Partial<TabsProps> = {
    orientation: 'horizontal',
};

export const Tabs = (props: TabsProps) => {
    const { children, ...context } = { ...defaultProps, ...props };

    return (
        <TabsProvider value={context}>
            <div css={tabs(context.orientation)}>
                <div css={tabList(context.orientation)} role="tablist">
                    {children}
                </div>
            </div>
        </TabsProvider>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are explicitly telling TypeScript that `defaultProps` can be undefined on instantiation (and all the other keys). Instead simply remove the explicit type and instead tell TypeScript this object is readonly (immutable) with the [`as const`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66993654/17954209) assertion

```js
const defaultProps = {
    orientation: 'horizontal',
} as const;
```

Alternatively, explicitly pick the keys you want and set to Required

```js
const defaultProps2: Required<Pick<TabsProps, 'orientation'>> = {
    orientation: 'horizontal'
}
```

[See on TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NlE2Xm)