# How to create typescript type based on object value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a object with all of our design tokens like this:

```
const Tokens = {
  neutralColor: {
    dark: {
      '100': #123456,
      '200': #223456,
    },
    medium: {
      '100': #654321,
      '200': #876543,
    },
    light: {
      '100': #009988,
      '200': #334411,
    }
  },
  feedbackColor: {
    // similar like above
  },
  // other color family here
}
```

In my componente I need to limit the `color` props to only accept values in the tokens, like:

```
<Typography color={Tokens.neutralColor.dark["100"]}>label</Typography>

// or

<Typography color="#123456">label</Typography>
// since Tokens.neutralColor.dark["100"] = #123456
```

As I should, I should create a type like:

```
type Color = "#123456" | "#223456" | "#654321" | "and so on"

type TypographyProps = {
  color: Color
}

function Typography(props: TypographyProps) { ... }
```

Is there a way to create this Typescript type dynamically based on my token object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible :

- declare your `Tokens` ["as const"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66993264/what-does-the-as-const-mean-in-typescript-and-what-is-its-use-case), so that your color are interpeted as a [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), not as `string` ;
- get the deep value of your object.

```
const Tokens = {
  neutralColor: {
    dark: {
      '100': '#123456',
      '200': '#223456',
    },
    medium: {
      '100': '#654321',
      '200': '#876543',
    },
    light: {
      '100': '#009988',
      '200': '#334411',
    }
  }
} as const;

type DeepValueOf<T> = T extends string ? T : DeepValueOf<T[keyof T]>;
type AllowedColor = DeepValueOf<typeof Tokens>;
```

<kbd>[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAKiA1gU0jAvDA3gKBjMZAVygCcBDAGwGERKRSAubPfGAE3NMWdzbYDkARgAMIgcwEBiIQCYAzABYArADYBAGlb8BssRJjTZCleq38AvubYBbZOwCWRG722DR4yVNXLF82UKabvi6%20l4AHADsPn5Bltb4lA4A5gAWUK78IR4G0mIAnPnh4XFZoZ6GUvJKikKBCTAWrE0WMOQQMKCQUADcODhQAJ4ADsgwACLIyMMAalREyADyAGYAPHAAfBjwMMgAHlCo7B3QpA5gyTAA-DvMk9NzlAsr6wDaKIMgy-AAuht9Q1GMAAgpR6AB3ey0eikbb3WbzJZrQHIL7wJCoCD-IA)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you so much! It just works for me! I got a little bit about `typeof` and `keyof`, reading about it now, thank you so much again!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get type of any part of your object.

Notice that:

- I changed your Tokens object to a constant
- You can get a type of any object with `typeof obj`
- you can get keys of any type T with `keyof T`

```ts
const Tokens = {
  neutralColor: {
    dark: {
      '100': '#123456',
      '200': '#223456',
    },
    medium: {
      '100': '#654321',
      '200': '#876543',
    },
    light: {
      '100': '#009988',
      '200': '#334411',
    }
  },
  feedbackColor: {
    // similar like above
  },
  // other color family here
} as const;



type LeafTypes<T> = T extends string
  ? T
  : {
      [Property in keyof T]: LeafTypes<T[Property]>;
    }[keyof T];

type Color = LeafTypes<typeof Tokens>
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAKiA1gU0jAvDA3gKBjMZAVygCcBDAGwGERKRSAubPfGAE3NMWdzbYDkARgAMIgcwEBiIQCYAzABYArADYBAGlb8BssRJjTZCleq38AvubYBbZOwCWRG722DR4yVNXLF82UKabvi6%20l4AHADsPn5Bltb4lA4A5gAWUK78IR4G0mIAnPnh4XFZoZ6GUvJKikKBCTAWrFasAGbI9gBG5MCItPRMLPwA9MMwEA42DpRcMEkoMOSdIABuyM3WozAgUKnIpDCgAzCt5FOUAJ4we6TrFosQh%20DQANw47zhQFwAOyDAAMshyK04D9kBAADxwAB8GHgMGQAA8oKh2I9oKQHGBkqwAPzwViZLIAbQACqQQL9SF8YFiYCgLiBWvAALrMQHA0G-SFwMkUqlfFnQt6WYkMpmst6fMEwfoMOEckFgyFfX4ShAoSDQnBAA)