# Is it possible to use static variables for type definitions?

Tags: typescript

I have some classes with a static variable indicating their type. I want to create a union type based on thoses static variables

```
class Foo {
  static typeId = 'i-am-foo';
}

class Bar {
  static typeId = 'i-am-bar';
}

type MyUnionType = Foo.typeId | Bar.typeId;
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oQC5iwS2GiwE8AHAUwEkATaAXmgHI8BaMAWxYDNFGBuVAF9UqUJBgAhMACcU6TDnyESFGvSasOLAEYz+QkSvLQAssQCqAOzzxLAFTLGGCeADojagD7Qp0945o+IA)

Unfortunately this is not possible, I get the error

> 'Foo' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here.

Is it possible to use static variables for type definitions?

Comment: Are you looking to construct `'i-am-foo' | 'i-am-bar'` or `string|string` ?

Comment: @TusharShahi I'm looking for `'i-am-foo' | 'i-am-bar'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`i-am-foo` and `i-am-bar` are values, and not types and you are trying to access them and combine to create a union. To do that correctly, you will need to get the type of them using [`typeof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html#the-typeof-type-operator).

Also, type your static values correctly using the right type. If you do not specify :

```
  static typeId :'i-am-foo'= 'i-am-foo';
```

the type of `typeId` would be the broad type `string`, and union of both `string` types will be `string`.

**Note:** One more way to do this would be:

```
  static typeId = 'i-am-foo' as const;
```

[`as const`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66993264/what-does-the-as-const-mean-in-typescript-and-what-is-its-use-case) will tell TS to try and find the narrowest type.

Your code would look like:

```
class Foo {
  static typeId :'i-am-foo'= 'i-am-foo';
}

class Bar {
  static typeId : 'i-am-bar' = 'i-am-bar';
}

type MyUnionType = typeof Foo.typeId | typeof Bar.typeId;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oQC5iwS2GiwE8AHAUwEkATaALgHI8BaMAW2YDNEGBeaJqw7d4DANyoAvqlShIMAEJgATinSYc+QiQo16Alu2YAjFQ2j9BR08vFSZO8tACyxAKoA7PPA8AVMk78jvCccIgAdI56AD5EASHQSsqRATRiQA)

Comment: Nit: Using a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) is probably a [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)er choice than a single [string literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) type annotation in this case.

Comment: @jsejcksn I have added both as you can see. But what is the reason I wonder for the preference?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74357301/is-it-possible-to-use-static-variables-for-type-definitions#comment131270360_74357461) Your initial answer didn't include it (but I see that you edited it in after I started composing my comment) — Neither prevents reassignment of the same value (e.g. `Foo.typeId = 'i-am-foo';`), but the const assertion more clearly indicates the intention, I think.

Comment: @baitendbidz If you have a lot of classes with the same discriminant property, you can also use this syntax for the union in order to avoid repeating the property name each time: [`(typeof Foo | typeof Bar)['typeId']`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oQC5iwS2GiwE8AHAUwEkATaAXmgHI8BaMAWxYDNFHpJoweADtsAblQBfVKlCQYAITAAnFOkw58hEhRr0mrDiwBGKvgKGisE6ah3loAWWIBVYXhEAVMg4YAKe3guOERoAB8iHyDoJWUASgBtRnsaRgBdCSA)

Comment: @jsejcksn I found the other way of writing to be more clear tbh. But I think it is just a matter of preference. Definitely agree with the shortcut you have added in the 2nd comment. Would you want to edit the answer or should i add it?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74357301/is-it-possible-to-use-static-variables-for-type-definitions/74357461?noredirect=1#comment131294079_74357461) @TusharShahi Feel free: go for it.