# Calling class prototype methods via index with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-class

I would like to be able to call class prototype methods using bracket notation, so that the method name can be decided at run time:

```js
classInstance['methodName'](arg);
```

I am failing to do this properly with TypeScript:

```js
class Foo {
  readonly ro: string = '';
  constructor() {}
  fn(s: number) { console.log(s); }
}

const foo = new Foo();
const methods = ['fn'];

foo['fn'](0)

// Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type.
foo[methods[0]](1);

// This expression is not callable.
// Not all constituents of type 'string | ((s: number) => void)' are callable.
// Type 'string' has no call signatures.
foo[methods[0] as keyof Foo](1);
```

The above example is in the [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=false#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oCcCmYAm8AdiAJ5bwBc0EALpgJaEDm0AvNAOQcDc60wRWpgCuwGvEwAKAJQoAvnwBmhSRCqFhAWwBG2TLOT9B8ENgB0IeE1XTu0BQtQDCtaIsRtohbAHc4iGV5nV01sGgALeDwYdgBtDmUOAF1eVHd4eMSkyQAGaVRUAHpC6AAVEgAHbE5hQjxsRUZsPA5+MEJCeBpoXWhhCGboSCHCaEZ6gA9oGkrzNMRY0IioiFicpOyARlsC4rLw+hhsCYqcKHoiMZhO7uAwEHBtUzMikoA5LqGHoxcaehphNhCDQYPBFNNZpwhIwWAAfaCSVTqLS6fRsAB80AAbvB6HhpK0wDg2g8wE85ntylUoXQYa1wsNOiSQNR6ExCGAAWcXulFmFItE1kkhjAANbYEhg-zwLa2IA).

I think that I have a reasonable understanding of what the errors mean and why the string literal in `foo['fn'](0)` does not produce an error.  However, I don't understand how to prevent the errors.  I thought that I might be able to use [Extract](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to build a type comprising of Function, but I've failed to do that.

How can I produce a list of typed method names over which my code can iterate?  And better, is it possible for the class to export such a list so that users of the class can easily access them?

**Background Information**

I have a [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/) test that needs to iterate over a list of methods from a [Page Object Model](https://playwright.dev/docs/pom), producing a screenshot for each.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m33Pqm) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz That works, beautifully. Thanks to [your other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66993654/340355), I think I understand. Without `as const`, TypeScript infers the type of `string[]`: zero or more strings, or the types `undefined` and `string`. `as const` asserts that the array is a `readonly` tuple of exactly that string, and nothing else.  Please do create an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
const methods = ['fn'];
```

The compiler infers the type of `methods` as `string[]`, which means it may contain any number of any strings at all.  So the compiler does not keep track of exactly *which* values are in the array, or where they are.  This allows you to do things later like

```
methods.push("hello");
```

Often, this is what people want when they initialize a variable.  But in your case, it is a problem, because then `methods[0]` could be any string whatsoever (or `undefined` if you have [the `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#checked-indexed-accesses---nouncheckedindexedaccess) enabled).

---

If you want the compiler to keep track of the exact [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the values in the array, the easiest way to do so is with a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
const methods = ['fn'] as const;
```

This tells the compiler that you would like to treat `methods` as essentially unchanging, and that it should infer the most specific type it can, more or less.  Now `methods` is inferred to be of type

```
// const methods: readonly ["fn"]
```

which means that the compiler knows that `methods` is a [readonly tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#readonly-tuples) containing exactly one element, whose type is the string literal type `"fn"`.

So now the compiler knows that `methods[0]` is `"fn"`, and your call compiles with no error:

```
foo[methods[0]](1); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=false#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oCcCmYAm8AdiAJ5bwBc0EALpgJaEDm0AvNAOQcDc60wRWpgCuwGvEwAKAJQpoAXz4AzQpIhVCwgLYAjbJlnJ+g+CGwA6EPCZrp3BakWoBhWtCWI20QtgDucRBleFzctbBoAC3g8GHYAbQ4VDgBdaEhjVxpeAHpsjNDwqJiqHHwiUmg4gCIVKuTUVA94BKTkyQAGaQamuLDI6Ig49uS2gEY7aFzoeABrMBJUIA)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your `methods` array is typed as an array containing only valid method names:

```
const methods: ('fn' | …)[] = ['fn'];
```

Notice that

```
const methods: (keyof Foo)[] = ['fn'];
```

doesn't cut it because `Foo` has also other keys (e.g. `ro`) that are not the names of methods, or the names of methods with a different signature than you need.

You can also just use

```
const methods = ['fn'] as const;
```