# Javascript equivalent of Typescript const assertion

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

What is the `javascript` equivalent for `typescript`'s const assertion?

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4] as const
```

I want to achieve this `array` in javascript to avoid further mutation.

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66993654), at runtime, there is no difference with using `as const`. So, what is the expected behavior in javascript and why do you need this? Do you want avoid mutations on `arr`?

Comment: yes, I want to avoid mutations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Use [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
Object.freeze(arr);

arr.push(8); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot add property 5, object is not extensible
```