# TS2322 when assigning cachelocation to localstorage in Typescript react auth0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, auth0

I have the following code

```
const providerConfig = {
    domain: config.domain,
    clientId: config.clientId,
    onRedirectCallback,
    useRefreshTokens: true,
    // advancedOptions:{defaultScope: 'openid profile email offline_access'},
    cacheLocation: 'localstorage',
    authorizationParams: {
        redirect_uri: window.location.origin,
        ...(config.audience ? { audience: config.audience } : null),
    },
};


ReactDOM.render(
    <Auth0Provider  {...providerConfig}>
        <Root />
    </Auth0Provider>
    , document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Referencing [this](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0-single-page-app-sdk#change-storage-options), trying to set `cacheLocation` to `localstorage` to I can use refresh tokens but I get this error:

```
Type '{ children: Element; domain: string; clientId: string; onRedirectCallback: (appState: any) => void; useRefreshTokens: boolean; cacheLocation: string; authorizationParams: { audience?: string; redirect_uri: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Auth0ProviderOptions'.
  Types of property 'cacheLocation' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"localstorage" | "memory" | undefined'.  TS2322
```

After some research I find solutions for similar problems but not this in particular, some things I've tried were adding an exclamation after the string `cacheLocation: 'localstorage'!,` a question mark after `cacheLocation` so it would be `cacheLocation?`, using tilda's to surround the string instead of single quotes, and also double quotes, does anyone know how I can assign `cacheLocation` to `localstorage` here?

Comment: Does it work if you add `as const` at the end of the object or string declaration? (`const providerConfig = { ... } as const` or `cacheLocation: 'localstorage' as const`,). (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66993264/what-does-the-as-const-mean-in-typescript-and-what-is-its-use-case) what it does)

Comment: @A_A it looks like that gets rid of the error, i'm assuming the functionality still works though I've not implemented the full intent yet.

Comment: Ok, I'll write it as an answer then with a bit more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that at `cacheLocation: 'localstorage'` Typescript stores it as type `string` and looses the information about the exact string content. If you mark it as readonly instead it will keep the precise type `"localstorage"` instead.

Therefore following works:

```js
const providerConfig = {
    // ...
    cacheLocation: 'localstorage' as const, // <--- note the as const here
    // ...
};


ReactDOM.render(
    <Auth0Provider  {...providerConfig}>
        <Root />
    </Auth0Provider>
    , document.getElementById('root')
);
```