# How to make function arguments arrays that not intersect?

Tags: typescript

At all, my aim is to make a function that takes 2 string arrays as arguments and the second one should not include elements of the first:

```js
function doSomething<
    const T extends string,
    const K extends StringExcept<T>
>(
    firstArray: T[],
    secondArray: K[]
) {}

doSomething(['a', 'b'], ['c', 'b'])  // 'b' in the second array should cause type error
```

Firstly, I thought, that I need a type type like `type StringExcept<T>`, which should work this way:

```js
type NotAbc = StringExcept<'abc'>;
const notAbcArray:NotAbc[] = [
    'any string',   // okay
    '123',          // okay
    'abc'           // not allowed
]
```

What i have tried is using `Exclude<>` type, like `Exclude<string, 'abc'>`, but it does not work like this, and gives just `string` type. Also I have tried different variations like `T extends K ? never : T` statement, but then I found out that type Exclude does literally the same

Then I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75438479/excluding-specific-strings-from-type) question, which says that type like `StringExcept` is impossible in TS for now (but if there are some updates, I would like to know). Also I have seen [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317) experimental feature, that is closed now.

So, is there a way to make my `doSomething(firstArray, secondArray)` function, using type like `StringExcept` or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [the `Exclude` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) within the type of `secondArray` itself:

```
function doSomething<
  const T extends string,
  const U extends string
>(
  firstArray: T[],
  secondArray: Exclude<U, T>[]
) { }
```

This will cause `U` to be inferred as the elements of `secondArray`, and then *checked* against `Exclude<U, T>`:

```
doSomething(['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']); // okay

doSomething(['a', 'b'], ['c', 'b']); // error! 
// -------------------------> ~~~
// Type '"b"' is not assignable to type '"c"'.
```

This works because both `T` and `U` will (hopefully) be a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), and `Exclude` can filter such unions (whereas it cannot filter non-union types like `string` itself).

It would be even nicer if we could put `Exclude<U, T>` in the [constaint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) for `U` instead, like `const U extends string & Exclude<U, T>`, but that is seen by the compiler as illegally circular.  So we can move it down into the parameter type.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEzgZTgWwKZQBYxgDmAPAFCKIQIDOUiAKotgB5TZjI2J0BOhRADQUqtegFVmbDlx5R+xMgD4AFCOAxedAIK9eAQwCeALkYBtALrDKNbNU66DJxAFEWEADYhk2EuMGMSpZkAJSIAN6IAL5kZKgYOPgCKmYA5PqpAakARqlWiGkQmYipyHkhANyIAPTViHAA1kax8Vi4BMQp6cU5eQGFPbkWlTV12HpwvACEiGS1iAC0S8srq2srSogAfjtzdQyGAA7YJQBE2aepiDDcYHD0+jQ0MERg+tkeJ1BwiFBHJ6lThBLgA6WJAA)