# How to infer type from array of strings?

Tags: typescript

### next-i18next.config.js

```js
const nextI18NextConfig = {
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: "fr",
    locales: ["en", "fr"],
    reloadOnPrerender: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
  },
}

module.exports = nextI18NextConfig
```

### topics.json

```json
{
  "feedback-introduction": {
    "fr": {
      "name": "Introduction à la rétroaction"
    },
    "en": {
      "name": "Introduction to feedback"
    }
  }
}
```

### topics.tsx

```
…
import i18n from "./next-i18next.config.js"
import topics from "./topics.json"

export default () => {
  const { locale } = useRouter()
  const { t } = useTranslation("common")
  var localizedTopics: string[] = []
  for (const [slug, topic] of Object.entries(topics)) {
    localizedTopics.push(topic[locale as "en" | "fr"].name)
  }
  …
}
```

Instead of using `locale as "en" | "fr"`, I would like to infer `"en" | "fr"` programatically from `locales` in `next-i18next.config.js`.

Is that possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the "as const" mean in TypeScript and what is its use case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66993264/what-does-the-as-const-mean-in-typescript-and-what-is-its-use-case)

Comment: It doesn’t… attempting to reformulate question.

Comment: What do you mean you can't use `const`? Just put it in the other file? Please edit the question to have sufficient detail to state the issue.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the problem is: 1. The file containing `const nextI18NextConfig = ...` is somewhere in `node_modules`;
2. It is in Javascript and doesn't provide type declarations. Is this correct?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov assumptions are very close… see updated question.

Answer (score 2):

> Can one infer type of i18n.locales programatically from another file?

In short: if the exporting source does not provide the literal type information that you want, then it will not be available to the compiler.

String literal types can be [inferred](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) at the numeric indexes of the array if the exporting file provides string literal type information. Otherwise, array element types are inferred using what's described as [best common type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#best-common-type) in the handbook.

Here's an example:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/PTAEEsFsAcHsCcAuoDeBDe80E8CMBfUAM3lklACIA6YAZzIFMB9SWAEwFcAbBqgK1oUA3ACgAxrAB2tZBix5QAXlABtCmgoAaSgCMtlMRQC6oxNmgNQAUR6QGkxLiWgzF2EVBycuFZI6QdBngTEVAwkAA9AH4RcSkZT0wcACZnNQ1tCj1MwyNPWlAJaURTc0sbBjsHVOVXBndE+WTff0Dg0TDQSJi44sacAGYALlAACnUKUAAfXUmZikNpyjYKAEoVPOV0-Syd3NKLa1t7RAHnOoavbAGWgKCQzu6RIA)

```ts
// import {array1} from "./some_module.js";
const array1 = ["a", "b", "c"];
type Element1 = typeof array1[number];
   //^? type Element1 = string

const array2 = ["a", "b", "c"] as const;
type Element2 = typeof array2[number];
   //^? type Element2 = "a" | "b" | "c"

const array3: ("a" | "b" | "c" | "d")[] = ["a", "b", "c"];
type Element3 = typeof array3[number];
   //^? type Element3 = "a" | "b" | "c" | "d"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have `import i18n from "./next-i18next.config.js"` then the file *is* under your control. If for some reason it has to be JS and not TS, but you can change the file itself, it may be possible to use https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html. But I have not been able to get it to work.

```
const en = /** @type {const} */("en");
const fr = /** @type {const} */("fr");

const locales = /** @type {const} */([en, fr]);

const nextI18NextConfig = /** @type {const} */({
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: "fr",
    locales: ["en", "fr"],
    reloadOnPrerender: false,
  },
});
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/LAKAxg9gdgzgLgAgKZQQXgQegFTYQATgE8AHJBAb0ljgF8FtMAKAIhRYEoBuUa%20BAGYAndFlwFiZSnzoNmLYZx4he0fgBsIYAIbqkMUTjyFS5KmtmMmAbRQAaQUIC63UKpoIoSAB5wAkgCMABwAcj5wAMLQAgCWAOaG4iZS5jT0VhSgCAgxwVAAXJRZ2QgAJkgC2gCu6nAAMlq6SIUKQix2xdmaOnowhdZsUO0IrSxOHSAlCEJImtqlAPJQAAozM1DlQoWV6jBIE9m0E7QcQA)

You can see `en` and `fr` have desired types, but it doesn't work for `locales` or `nextI18NextConfig` and I wasn't able to find a syntax which does.

Instead my suggestion would be to actually define the config in a TS file with `as const`. Then `./next-i18next.config.js` can simply import and reexport it.