# define the keys of an object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following object:

```
type Currencies = "tl" | "us-dollar" | "euro"
const currenciesMap = {}
```

I want to say that the keys of this object must be one of the values defined in the Currencies type.

So the object is going to seem as follows:

```
const currenciesMap = {
  tl: "₺",
  "us-dollar": "$",
  euro: "€"
}
```

So typescript should only allow these keys to be defined.

How to make this type?

I thought this would work but it didn't:

```
const currenciesMap: { [key: Currencies[string]]: string } = {}
```

Typescript shows the following error:

```
An index signature parameter type must be 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or a template literal type.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const currencies = {
  tl: "₺",
  "us-dollar": "$",
  euro: "€"
} as const


type Currency = typeof currencies[keyof typeof currencies]
```

## Usage

```
const log = (currency: Currency) => console.log(currency);
log(currencies.euro)
```

Or:

```
log("€")
```

#### More info:

[What does the "as const" mean in TypeScript and what is its use case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66993264/what-does-the-as-const-mean-in-typescript-and-what-is-its-use-case)

Comment: What is `as const` doing?

Comment: This answer doesn't really responds to the question: "I want to say that the keys of this object must be one of the values defined in the Currencies type." Here you build the type from the object

Comment: @nook. They have written <So typescript should only allow these keys to be defined.> also.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for Typescript `Record` utility type. It is documented [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)

`Record` is equivalent to

```ts
type Record<K extends string | number | symbol, T> = { [P in K]: T }
```

```ts
type Currencies = "tl" | "us-dollar" | "euro"
const currenciesMap: Record<Currencies, string> = {
  tl: "₺",
  "us-dollar": "$",
  euro: "€"
}
```

Note that when declaring your variable as a record this way, you will be forced to declare all the properties possible. If you don't want to have them all, you could wrap it around `Partial`

```ts
type Currencies = "tl" | "us-dollar" | "euro"
const currenciesMap: Partial<Record<Currencies, string>> = {
  tl: "₺",
  "us-dollar": "$",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to access `Currencies` with `[string]`. You should just say `K in Currencies`,  as follows:

```
type Currencies = 'tl' | 'us-dollar' | 'euro';

const currenciesMap: { [K in Currencies]: string } = {
  tl: '₺',
  'us-dollar': '$',
  euro: '€',
};
```