# How to avoid error message "Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string | string[]'."

Tags: javascript, typescript, astrojs

I get the message `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string | string[]'.`:

```js
const data = [
  ['1', ['11']],
  ['2', ['21']],
  ['3', ['31']],
]

data.map(topic => {
  topic[1].map(p => console.log(p))
})
```

What can I do to solve this (the error message, code works as expected)?

This is within an Astro project, JavaScript (no TypeScript), in case this is relevant.

[image]

Comment: `const data: [string, string[]][] = ...`? Using `as const` would probably also work, but without further information the compiler infers the type you're shown which _doesn't_ guarantee any given member of `topic` is an array. Also note that message is **from TypeScript** (hence `ts(2339)`), not Prettier _or_ ESLint.

Comment: O, so I guess I should specify that that `.astro` file is not in ts but in js, because I cannot specify type in js, right?

Comment: You can't _use TypeScript syntax_ in JavaScript files (assuming that's what `.astro` is), but they can (and in your case evidently _are_) still be type-checked. [_"Astro always treats your component code as TypeScript, and the Astro VSCode Extension will infer as much as it can to provide autocompletion, hints, and errors in your editor."_](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/typescript/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answers already pointed out, if you can change the file to TypeScript, you can explicitly type data:

```
const data: [string, string[]][] = [
  ["1", ["11"]],
  ["2", ["21"]],
  ["3", ["31"]]
];
```

If you need your file to remain in JavaScript, you can still explicitly type data, by using JSDoc syntax, which is recognized by most IDEs.

```
/**
 * @type {Array<[string, string[]]>}
 */
const data = [
  ['1', ['11']],
  ['2', ['21']],
  ['3', ['31']],
]

data.map(topic => {
  topic[1].map(p => console.log(p))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

### Why that happens?

Typescript looks to the array `['1', ['11']]` and infers the type as `(string | string[])[]`. `.map` exists in arrays but not in the string.

### To fix that:

1. Tell TypeScript that this array is constant and will not be changed by adding `as const` at the end of the array.

```
const data = [
  ['1', ['11']],
  ['2', ['21']],
  ['3', ['31']],
] as const

data.map(topic => {
  topic[1].map(p => console.log(p))
})
```

2. When using the `.map` method check the type:

```
const data = [
  ['1', ['11']],
  ['2', ['21']],
  ['3', ['31']],
]

data.map(topic => {
  if (Array.isArray(topic[1]) {
    topic[1].map(p => console.log(p))
  }

  // OR
  if (typeof topic[1] === "string") {
     doSomething()
  } else {
    topic[1].map(p => console.log(p))
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`data` is inferred as `(string | string[])[][]` per default by the TypeScript compiler. That type is not specific enough to call an array method such as `.map()` on an item because for TypeScript any item in the `data` array could either be a `string` or a `string[]`.

What you'll have to do is specifying the type of `data` in more detail. You can either do that with an [Explicit Type Annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables)...

```
const data: [string, string[]][] = [
  ["1", ["11"]],
  ["2", ["21"]],
  ["3", ["31"]]
];
```

... or by using an [`const`-assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66993654/12834972). That way TypeScript will use the *narrowest possible type* for your variable.

```
const data = [
  ["1", ["11"]],
  ["2", ["21"]],
  ["3", ["31"]]
] as const;

data.map(topic => {
  topic[1].map(p => console.log(p));
});
```