# Define a global Typescript const file in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, constants

I would like to create a global const file for my Angular project. Now after doing some research there are multiple ways of creating such:

1. const class (readonly modifier doesn't work at runtime)
2. const file (missing differentiation between multiple contexts)
3. environment files (only for environment-specific use cases)

But each seem to have some downsides as mentioned above.

Now I just tried it anyway with the const file. But only with a single big const object. Simliar to Angular environment files. Now to make it unmutable I added the Readonly type as well as the Object.freeze function to it:

```
export const constants: Readonly<any> = Object.freeze({
  Context:
    {
      PI: 3.14159265359,
      WEATHER: 'https://goweather.herokuapp.com/weather/',
    },
   AnotherContext: {...}
})
```

Would this be the right approach or am I still missing some points here? Thank you!

Comment: You could also use a service class with an immutable property that's injectable wherever needed and is also a singleton if provided in the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You select the right option - have separate file with exported const(s). Just for typescript you have better option to write it. Use `as const` to make each property of the object readonly:

```
export const constants = {
  Context:
    {
      PI: 3.14159265359,
      WEATHER: 'https://goweather.herokuapp.com/weather/',
    },
   AnotherContext: {...}
} as const;
```

You can read more about how it works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66993264/what-does-the-as-const-mean-in-typescript-and-what-is-its-use-case)